# Non cumulative histogram function in influxdb flux

Tags: histogram, influxdb

I am new to flux in influxdb, and trying to write flux query for generating histogram. The function in flux given in documentation `https://docs.influxdata.com/flux/v0.24/functions/built-in/transformations/histogram/`

is a cumulative histogram function giving cumulative result. I do not want this and want individual counts.

How can I do that

Answer (score 1):

On my knowledges, the workaround is to compute difference with element n-1 for each individual count:

```
histogram output: 72  72  75  80
individual count: 72   0   3   5
```